# Pandas convert columns with every cell is ndarray to list in every cell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where each cell is an 1D ndarray.
I want to convert them to be a list.
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: `df.applymap(list)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one column use:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(list)
df['col'] = df['col'].map(list)
```

For all columns:

```
df = df.applymap(list)
```

If need processing some columns:

```
cols = ['col1','col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `map`:

```
df['col'] = list(map(list, df['col']))
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
df['col'] = [list(i) for i in df['col']]
```

Or use `pd.eval`:

```
df['col'] = pd.eval(df['col'])
```